# Установка ZeosLib на Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, mysql

Не могу установить Zeos на Delphi 2009. Единственная инфа - это [установка компонента ZeosLib на Delphi 2009 - 2010 для работы с MySQL](http://androschuk.blogspot.com/2010/06/zeoslib-delphi-2009-2010-mysql.html). Но он не открывается.

Comment: Спасибо конечно за очки уважения? но вы ими лучше не разбрасывайтесь пока не накопите достаточно количество, на этом форуме от них много что зависит. <br>Я в начале тоже так разбрасывался, а потом не мог понять что к чему. <br>Надо бы обратиться к администрации с предложением: новички не могут дарить очки, +возможность писать в личку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все открывается - БлогСпот заблокирован - вы случаем не из Казахстана? :) Земляком будете :)
Используйте http-прокси для доступа к заблокированным сайтам, например [**DaiDostup.ru**](http://DaiDostup.ru)
Больше ничем не могу помочь, вы дали слишком мало инфы о вашей проблеме.

Answer (score 0):

Вот статья: [Delphi установка компонентов ZEOS для подключения к MySQL, SQLite...](http://mirsovetov.net/zeos-install.html)